# Picture gallery slider with border not uniform

Tags: border

Hi I am now using the jssor slider picture gallery on another part of the site and added a 1px border to the slider1_container div however it looks wrong, on the bottom and right it is as it should be 1px but on the left and top it is about 2px and I can't find out why.

I have played with all the CSS for the slider but can't stop the 1px border I am applying to slider1_container div from looking like 2px on the left and top.

Anyone got any idea what I need to do

Here is the code for slider1_container

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 330px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #e4e9eb; border: 1px solid #8dc0e8; overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a wrapper to add border.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #8dc0e8;">
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 330px; height: 356px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #e4e9eb; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I reverted back to using no slider just because of this problem. I will try this out next time. Thanks for the answer